# ANTLR3 Kleene star and tree traversal

Tags: antlr3, tree-traversal

I'm an experienced yacc/bison abuser.  I'm used to building my own trees and then traversing them.  So, now, switching to ANTLR3 (why 3? Because 4 doesn't support Python, that's why!)...  I have the following syntax:

```
symbol : ID fields          -> ^(NAME ID fields);

fields : (DOT ID)*          -> ^(FIELD ID*);
```

And my tree grammar fragment is:

```
names: ^(NAME id=. fields) ;

fields: ^(FIELD .*) ;
```

The resulting tree for "let z = a.b.c" is:

```
(LETS (LET z (NAME a (FIELD b c))))
```

And the walker says:

> node from line 1:10 mismatched input u'b' expecting

Various attempts to introduce + instead of * have failed in other ways.  Maybe there's documentation on how exactly the tree walker works for * and + but I didn't find it (like some people and refridgerators?).